# PHP: Send Values To HTML Form With Curl In PHP

Tags: php, html, post, curl, methods

Excuse me for my question ...
This has been discussed many times but i didn't notice... :(
we have this html form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Comment</title>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<legend align="center">Comments</legend>
<form action="server.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br><br>
Email: <input type="email" name="email" /><br><br>
Web: <input type="url" name="web" /><br><br>
Message:<br>
<textarea name="comment"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

and this php file:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$web = $_POST['web'];
$comment = nl2br($_POST['comment']);
//database variables;
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "ashiyane";
//connect to mysql & insert data into table;
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
if ($connection){
    echo "Connected Successfully...";
    $select_db = mysql_select_db($db);
    if ($select_db && $name !== "" && $web !=="" && $email !=="" && $comment !==""){
        echo "<br>Database Selected...";
        $run_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (name,email,web,comment) VALUES              ('$name','$email','$web','$comment')");
        if ($run_query){
            echo "<br>Data Have Been Insert ...<br>";
        }else{
            echo "<br>Inserting Data Failed!";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<br>Database No Selected!";
    }
}else{
    echo "<br>Connecting Failed!";
}
//show results;
$show_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($show_query)){
    echo $results['name']." : ".$results['email']." : ".$results['web']." : ".$results['comment']."<br>====================<br>";
}
?>
```

Now we want our values to send HTML form with curl functions ...
please help me ...
Once again I apologize for asking this question... :)
Thanks All Friend !! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming curl is installed and enabled on the server, you should be able to do something like:

```
<?php
$post_data = array(
    'name' => 'Your Name',
    'email' => 'user@example.com',
    'web' => 'http://www.example.com',
    'comment' => 'your comment',
)
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/path/to/comment/post/script");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
?>
```

Another alternative, and possibly a more flexible one would be to use [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
which will handle the http request and response for you.

As a side note, the script you posted is currently dangerously written, you are directly inserting user provided data into the database without escaping it (e.g. by using mysql_real_escape_string), ideally you should be using a prepared statement via [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or similar